# Ubuntu 23.04 - My Steam app does not open

Tags: steam, 23.04

When I try to check if there is any problem with *Steam App* it shows:

```
Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
```

But it still does not open. I tried looking into my logs to check if there is any issue with *Steam App*, and nothing is wrong. I tried to remove and reinstall the app, but it does not open.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening it from the terminal?

Try with either just `steam` and check the terminal output for errors.
Or try `steam --gamepadui`.